# Custom image link in WooCommerce product category archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, product

Is there an easy way to set Woocommerce 3.x to link to full size image instead of the product details on the category pages (where you see the thumbs of products)?

So basically it will work as a gallery of some sort with an 'add to cart' buttons below each image.

I assume I have to edit the woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open() function at `includes\wc-template-functions.php` and change:

```
esc_url( get_the_permalink() )
```

To something else…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Important note:**  Never override any core file as you can use available hooks
>   *(or also you can [override WooCommerce templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/))*…

To set Woocommerce 3.x to link to full size image on the category archive pages only, use this:

```
add_action ('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'custom_loop_product_link_open', 1);
function custom_loop_product_link_open(){
    // For product category archives pages only
    if(is_product_category()){
        // Remove default image link
        remove_action ('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10);
        // Add custom image link function
        add_action ('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'change_loop_product_link_open', 10);
    }
}

// Custom image link function
function change_loop_product_link_open(){
    global $product; // Get the WC_Product object

    echo '<a href="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $product->get_id(), 'full' )  . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link">';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works…

Comment: Thank you very much, it works really nicely. Not sure why haven't they added such a feature into the plugin.

Also added the following to functions.php, however it seems to me that only on the gallery page is lightbox enabled, will have to add a rel="lightbox" or something to the a tag.... 
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );

But that's not of your concerns. Thank you again!